# Pass class object by reference to method override

Tags: c#

I've been attempting to write a section of code for this project so that it can print out whichever BasePlayer object's hand along with the total as such (:    (card)    (card)    (total) - (playerName)) and I've been trying to override ToString() to be able to accomplish this. Issue is I need to pass the referenced object's specific hand but can't figure out how to pass by reference while using an override. I'm not sure if it's syntax or how I'm doing it, I would just like to fix it.

The issue is the bottom most function:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Blackjack_C;

namespace Blackjack_C
{
    public class BasePlayer : Hand
    {
        public string name;
        private (ref BasePlayer ap);

        public BasePlayer(ref string name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }

        Hand hand = new Hand();
        public bool IsBusted()
        {
            return hand.getTotal() > 21;
        }

        public void Bust()
        {
            Console.Write(name + " busts.");
        }

        public override string ToString(ref BasePlayer ap)
        {
            string output = ":\t";
            if (!(ap.m_Cards.Count == 0))
            {
                foreach (var c in ap.m_Cards)
                {
                    output += (c + "\t");
                }
                if (ap.getTotal() != 0)
                {
                    output += ("(" + ap.getTotal() + ")");
                }
                return output;
            }
            else
            {
                return("<empty>");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the definition of the Hand class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using Blackjack_C;

namespace Blackjack_C
{
    public class Hand
    {
        protected List<Card> m_Cards;

        ~Hand()
        {
            clearHand();
        }

        public void add(Card pCard)
        {
            m_Cards.Insert(m_Cards.Count, pCard);
        }

        public void clearHand()
        {
            m_Cards.Clear();
        }

        public int getTotal()
        {
            // If the hand is empty it cannot get total
            if (m_Cards.Count == 0)
            {
                return 0;
            }

            // Gets total value of deck (doesn't run if Dealer's hand)
            int total = 0;
            foreach (var c in m_Cards) 
            {
                total += c.getValue();
            }

            // Bool to check if the hand has an Ace in it (doesn't run if Dealer's hand)
            bool containsAce = false;
            foreach (var c in m_Cards)
            {
                if (c.getValue() == (int) Card.card_face.Ace)
                {
                    containsAce = true;
                }
            }

            // Checks if hand is dealer's hand and get's value whilst keeping it secret from the player
            if (m_Cards.First().getValue() == 0)
            {
                //int total = 0;
                foreach (var c in m_Cards)
                {
                    total += c.getDealerValue();
                }
                //bool containsAce = false;
                foreach (var c in m_Cards)
                {
                    if (c.getDealerValue() == (int) Card.card_face.Ace)
                    {
                        containsAce = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Checks if total is less than 11 to see if changing Ace to = 11 instead of = 1 is necessary
            if (containsAce && total <= 11)
            {
                total += 10;
            }
            return total;
        }

        public Card getCard(int index)
        {
            if (index >= m_Cards.Count || index < 0)
                return m_Cards[0];
            else
            {
                return m_Cards[index];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry for lack of a good post, this is my first time posting a question here.

Comment: Create a `Hand` field for your class, set the `Hand` field in your constructor, access this inside your override of `ToString`

Comment: Can you add the definition of the `Hand` class? In addition, it makes little to no sense to both create an instance of hand in your class as well as inherit from hand. What is the relationship between the two? Most likely a `BasePlayer` is not an extension of `Hand`.

Answer (score 0):

i created the hand object with assumptions. Hand can have 2 or more card.
so you can try like this :

```
public class BasePlayer
    {
        public Hand Hand { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public BasePlayer(ref string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }

        public bool IsBusted()
        {
            return Hand.GetTotal() > 21;
        }

        public void Bust()
        {
            Console.Write(Name + " busts.");
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            // you can access referenced string and specific hand on here
            return string.Join(' ',Hand.Cards.Select(card=>$"{(card)}")) + $" {(Hand.GetTotal()) } "+ Name;
        }
    }

    public class Hand
    {
        public List<int> Cards { get; set; }
        public int GetTotal()
        {
            return Cards.Sum();
        }
    }
```